# 2D PCA line fitting with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, math, regression, pca

I'm trying to implement a 2D PCA with numpy.
The code is rather simple:

```
import numpy as np

n=10
d=10
x=np.linspace(0,10,n)
y=x*d

covmat = np.cov([x,y])
print(covmat)

eig_values, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eig(covmat)
largest_index = np.argmax(eig_values)
largest_eig_vec = eig_vecs[largest_index]
```

The covariance matrix is:

```
[[   11.31687243   113.16872428]
 [  113.16872428  1131.6872428 ]]
```

Then I've got a simple helper method to plot a line (as a series of points) around a given center, in a given direction.
This is meant to be used by pyplot, therefore I'm preparing separate lists for the x and y coordinate.

```
def plot_line(center, dir, num_steps, step_size):
    line_x = []
    line_y = []
    for i in range(num_steps):
        dist_from_center = step_size * (i - num_steps / 2)
        point_on_line = center + dist_from_center * dir
        line_x.append(point_on_line[0])
        line_y.append(point_on_line[1])
    return (line_x, line_y)
```

And finally the plot setup:

```
lines = []
mean_point=np.array([np.mean(x),np.mean(y)])
lines.append(plot_line(mean_point, largest_eig_vec, 200, 0.5))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.scatter(x,y, c="b", marker=".", s=10
           )
for line in lines:
    ax.plot(line[0], line[1], c="r")

ax.scatter(mean_point[0], mean_point[1], c="y", marker="o", s=20)

plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, the PCA doesn't seem to work.
Here's the plot:

[image: pca line fitting]

I'm afraid I've got no idea what went wrong.

- I've computed the covariance manually -> same result.
- I've checked the other eigenvalue -> perpendicular to the red line.
- I've tested plot_line with the direction (1,10). It's perfectly aligned to my points:
  [image: perfectly aligned]

**The final plot shows that the line fitted by pca is the correct result only it is mirrored at the y axis.**

In fact, if I change the x coordinate of the eigenvector, the line is fitted perfectly:

[image: perfect fit]

Apparently this is a fundamental problem. Somehow I've misunderstood how to use pca.

Where is my mistake ?
Online resources seem to describe PCA exactly as I implemented it.
I don't believe I have to categorically mirror my line-fits at the y-axis. It's got to be something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mistake is that you're extracting the last *row* of the eigenvector array. But the eigenvectors form the *columns* of the eigenvector array returned by `np.linalg.eig`, not the rows. From the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html):

> [...] the arrays a, w, and v satisfy the equations `dot(a[:,:], v[:,i]) = w[i] * v[:,i]` [for each `i`]

where `a` is the array that `np.linalg.eig` was applied to, `w` is the 1d array of eigenvalues, and `v` is the 2d array of eigenvectors. So the columns `v[:, i]` are the eigenvectors.

In this simple two-dimensional case, since the two eigenvectors are mutually orthogonal (because we're starting with a symmetric matrix) and unit length (because `np.linalg.eig` normalises them that way), the eigenvector array has one of the two forms

```
[[ cos(t)  sin(t)]
 [-sin(t)  cos(t)]]
```

or

```
[[ cos(t)  sin(t)]
 [ sin(t) -cos(t)]]
```

for some real number `t`, and in the first case, reading the first row (for example) instead of the first column would give `[cos(t), sin(t)]` in place of `[cos(t), -sin(t)]`. This explains the apparent reflection that you're seeing.

Replace the line

```
largest_eig_vec = eig_vecs[largest_index]
```

with

```
largest_eig_vec = eig_vecs[:, largest_index]
```

and you should get the expected results.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.